# Read data in a url in R

Tags: r, url, readr, read-data

I want to read the data in the following url into R but I couldn't do it.
Does anyone have any idea about it?? Thanks!
http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/
I need the data Ozone

Comment: I would try right clicking the "data" link and downloading it as a text file. Then you could use read.table() with tab separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data is hosted at http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/datasets/ozone.data

The values are tab-separated, so you can read it using `read_tsv` from the readr package:

```r
library(readr)
read_tsv("http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/datasets/ozone.data")
```

This will read the data directly from the website, so you won't need to download it manually yourself.

Comment: Thanks! But somehow when i tried to load the readr package, it gave me                       
  Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘readr’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]): namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.2 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.5 is required    error message. But I couldn't update the package. Do you know why?

Comment: Did you already try installing/updating the package with `install.packages("readr")`?

Comment: Should I try updating R?

Comment: Try `install.packages("rlang")`

Comment: I installed rlang and tried to do library(readr) again but it gave me this error message:Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘readr’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘cli’

Comment: there is no package called ‘cli’............what is cli.....I didn't call a package called cli

Comment: readr uses the package 'cli'. One more thing to try:

`remove.packages("readr")`, then
`install.packages("readr", dependencies = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you very much~~

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider accepting the answer (click the check mark) if it fixed your issue. Thanks!